# Injecting C code inside a C#/.NET assembly as part of the build process

Tags: c#, c, .net, msbuild, roslyn

I have a .NET Framework 3.5 project and I want to enable framework rollover for it so that the user can run it on a system with either .NET Framework 3.5 or .NET Framework 4.x runtime installed. That should allow the user to run my app with any out-of-the-box installation of Windows starting with Windows 7.

I already have this working using the following `App.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- This configuration file is required by the apphost which runs on legacy .NET Framework for compatibility reasons -->

<configuration>
    <!-- Prefer .NET 3.5 (preinstalled on Windows 7), rollover to .NET 4.x (preinstalled on Windows 8+) -->
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

However, I don't want to distribute the config file along with the app. I've read [this great post by Michal Strehovský](https://gist.github.com/MichalStrehovsky/d6bc5e4d459c23d0cf3bd17af9a1bcf5), which explains that I can get the same behavior by setting the `COMPLUS_OnlyUseLatestCLR=1` environment variable *before* my program's entry point is executed.

Michal achieves this by compiling C# code into a `netmodule` instead of a full assembly, and then merging the result with a C assembly that implements a TLS callback. That callback sets the environment variable when the program executes, but before the managed code gets picked up by the .NET runtime:

```c
#include <windows.h>

VOID WINAPI tls_callback(
    PVOID DllHandle,
    DWORD Reason,
    PVOID Reserved)
{
    if (Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        SetEnvironmentVariableW(L"COMPLUS_OnlyUseLatestCLR", L"1");
}

#ifdef _M_AMD64
    #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_used")
    #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:p_tls_callback")
    #pragma const_seg(push)
    #pragma const_seg(".CRT$XLAAA")
        EXTERN_C const PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK p_tls_callback = tls_callback;
    #pragma const_seg(pop)
#endif
#ifdef _M_IX86
    #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
    #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_p_tls_callback")
    #pragma data_seg(push)
    #pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLAAA")
        EXTERN_C PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK p_tls_callback = tls_callback;
    #pragma data_seg(pop)
#endif
```

**I want to implement his approach, but using the MSBuild project system to do as much of the heavy lifting as possible.**

In Michal's post, he used `csc` to compile C# code into a .NET module. I tried replicating that by changing my project's output type from `Exe` to `Module` like so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net35</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>module</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

However, that resulted in my first roadblock -- the compiler produced numerous errors related to C#'s [NRT feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

```
C:\Users\Tyrrr\.nuget\packages\quickjson\1.0.0\contentFiles\cs\any\QuickJson\JsonNull.cs(6,23): error CS0518: Predefine
d type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute' is not defined or imported [e:\Projects\Software\DotnetRunti
meBootstrapper\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli.csproj]

C:\Users\Tyrrr\.nuget\packages\quickjson\1.0.0\contentFiles\cs\any\QuickJson\JsonNull.cs(4,20): error CS0518: Predefine
d type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute' is not defined or imported [e:\Projects\Software\Dotn
etRuntimeBootstrapper\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli.csproj]

e:\Projects\Software\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli\Utils\ConsoleEx.cs(8,31): error CS
0518: Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute' is not defined or imported [e:\Project
s\Software\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli\DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper.AppHost.Cli.csproj
]

...


294 Error(s)
```

My project does use NRTs (it targets the latest version of C# and builds with .NET 7, despite targeting the .NET Fx 3.5 runtime), but they're polyfilled using the [PolySharp library](https://github.com/Sergio0694/PolySharp). I also tried using the [Nullable polyfill library](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable), but it resulted in the same issue.

Setting `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` doesn't resolve the issue either, because my code contains NRT annotations (i.e. `public MyClass? Foo()`). Is there a way to proceed without giving up on NRTs?

I tried googling around and found [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58193) on the Roslyn repository. It seems that compiling as .NET module is not officially supported in .NET Core. Still, given that I'm targeting .NET Framework and using .NET Core only in terms of SDK (with `csc` being the same either way), I suspect there might be a way to hack the build system to make it work?

Finally, assuming this issue is resolved, what would be the best way to compile some C code? I can probably include the C file as a `<None>` item within my project structure and run `cl` in an MSBuild target before `CoreBuild`, emulating what Michal did. However, perhaps there's some built-in way to achieve the same, maybe by referencing the existing targets that MSBuild uses for C/C++ workloads?

---

For context, this question is related to [this issue](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper/issues/3) on [DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper).

Comment: For the first problem, if you can't find a way to get the compilation to .netmodule working, just compile to a regular .exe, and "extract" the .netmodule from it. One way to do that is disassembling it with ildasm, remove the .assembly section, and reassemble with ilasm, changing the extension to .netmodule.

Also if you want to integrate it into MSBuiild, you can take a look at ILSupport as a base. It has some nice MSBuild targets do the process of ildasm/regexp substitution/ilasm.

Comment: @Leandro thanks for the tip. By ILSupport, do you mean this project? https://github.com/ins0mniaque/ILSupport

Comment: Sounds like the C# compiler is not injecting the nullable metadata attributes when compiled as a module outputtype. Have you tried adding [those attribute types](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md#nullable-metadata) manually?

Comment: @m0sa They are added by a source-only NuGet package. I haven't tried adding them manually though.